# Authenticate spring websocket via MessageMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket

### Problem

I have set up a stomp websocket on spring, and have endpoints defined via the `@MessageMapping` annotation.

I had read that `@PreAuthorize` could be used to authorize on a per mapping basis but this doesn't appear to work. When using the `@PreAuthorize`, the request is not denied when the user is not in a specific role.

---

### Code

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@MessageMapping(value="/addComment/{ID}")
public void addComment(@DestinationVariable Integer ID, String content, Principal principal)
        throws Exception {

//Do stuff with ID,content etc
}
```

I currently have it set up like so

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends
        AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages
                .simpDestMatchers("/put/addComment/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Although would prefer to annotate on each mapping since it is clearer for me.

---

### Question(s)

Can preauthorize be used with mappings?
If so is there a reason that it is not working in the above example?
If not, is there a way to do this per mapping, instead of in the configurer?

---

#### Extra

Using Spring 4

Any more information needed let me know